# How to use one = with multiple and/or

Tags: python

`while party!='R' and party!='D':`

can this be shortened to

`while party!='R' and 'D':`

`while party!=('R' and 'D'):`

or the like? (that is, is there any equivalent expression with only one party!=)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use multiple condition:

try this.

```
l=['R','D']
while party not in l:
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply create list and use like this

```
validList = ['R', 'S']
# You can also use not in operator for other condition
if party in validList:
    # Do your stuff here
    print("It's Present")
```